# How to get JavaScript calculation to appear in a text box

Tags: javascript, html

I'm experimenting with JavaScript, trying to get the result that I need.

I want the script to perform a basic calculation and appear in a text box on my webpage.

I am trying to do it this way:

```js
document.getElementById("mjd").innerHtml= (10+4)
```

```html
    <form>
    <input id="mjd" class="textbox2" type="text" name="mjd" placeholder="NNNNN" maxlength="5">
    </form>
```

and then elsewhere in the html I have:

Comment: Use `.value` to set `value` property value of input.

Comment: @Tushar It sets the property, not the attribute.

Comment: And make sure the `<script>` is included at the bottom of markup. Or wrap the code in `DOMContentLoaded`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
<script language="javascript">
document.getElementById("mjd").value= 10+4
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this - https://jsfiddle.net/3L31d89d/

**HTML:**

```
<form>
    <input id="mjd" class="textbox2" type="text" name="mjd" placeholder="NNNNN" maxlength="5">
</form>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
  document.getElementById("mjd").value = (10+4);
```

Answer (score 1):

use  `.value`

```js
document.getElementById("mjd").value= (10+4)
```

```html
 <form>
    <input id="mjd" class="textbox2" type="text" name="mjd" placeholder="NNNNN" maxlength="5">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need **value** attribute.  Then set the **value** attribute using JavaScript

```
<html>
<form>
  <input id="mjd" class="textbox2" type="text" name="mjd" value="" placeholder="NNNNN" maxlength="5">
</form>
<script>
  document.getElementById("mjd").value = 10 + 4;
</script>

</html>
```